# Parsing .plt or .got in memory

Tags: android, linux

I am looking for a solution that helps me check the PLT or GOT for signs of hooking. That leads me to two questions

- Do the PLT and GOT exist on disk in a binary or do they also get mapped to the memory when the binary is loaded?
- If they are also loaded in memory, can I parse the process memory to find those tables and list their entries?

I am asking these in context of Linux and Android and parsing my own process' memory for signs of hooking.